# css sprite navigation

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

Is it possible to use three images in CSS sprite navigation?

This may be like this

[My image http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1429/navigx.jpg](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1429/navigx.jpg)

If its possible what will be the result?

Comment: No, it does not work with prime numbers... seriously, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any amount of images in a sprite, just move the positioning around in your CSS:

```
.sprite1
{
background-image:url(../../upload/btn_continue_sprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: -10px 5px;
}

.sprite1:hover
{
background-image:url(../../upload/btn_continue_sprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: -20px 10px;
}

.sprite2
{
background-image:url(../../upload/btn_continue_sprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: -30px 15px;
}

.sprite2:hover
{
background-image:url(../../upload/btn_continue_sprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: -40px 20px;
}
```

Just have to figure out the px distances to align the sprite to the element properly and you're away!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. See exaple here 
http://www.ehousestudio.com/blog/view/css_sprite_navigation_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can use any number of images in a sprite. Depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If done right this will be the result:

[alt text http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1429/navigx.jpg](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/1429/navigx.jpg)

Comment: I know it's lame. But I have no idea what OP wants :)