# Moving A sprite position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, attributes, sprite

I have an image that is a sprite, I want to move the scroll location onClick of another div with jquery please help

```
.top-background{
    background: url("../images/mainall.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
    height: 888px;
    width:1024px;
}
```

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#divToClick").click(function(){
  $("#yourElementId").scrollTo(//location where to scroll);

});
```

here is the [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in earlier question
[About sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060824/css-sprite-navigation)

and it is tutorial about sprite again.. [CSS sprite](http://www.ehousestudio.com/blog/view/css_sprite_navigation_tutorial)

If u want to do it with jquery :

```
 $('.top-background').css('background-position', 'position_to_show_next_image');
```

and attach it with event method hover or what do you want to do..

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you if you are trying to scroll an image background. - http://youlove.us/blog/the-youloveus-scrolling-background-effect-explained